# Frustrating issue with UISearchDisplayController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I've been working on adding search bars to my app, and have run into a problem using the UISearchController. For the most part things are straightforward, and is 95% working (the 5% is where hopefully you come in :)

I know it's something with my methodology since I've managed to reproduce the problem with a very small xcode project with just a table view controller, a search bar, and a segue to a detail window.

In a nutshell, I can enter search text, it filters the results properly, I can click on a row, it segues to the detail VC properly - so far so good.

[image]

However, when I *return* from the detail window, the rows in the search results are blank. Important to note that the *number of rows* is correct - it's just that they're blank

[image]

Does anyone know what the heck is going on here? It's surely something silly, but I've run out of ideas. The super-simple xcode project is [available](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/481022/SearchTest.zip) as well, which may be easier to understand than my lame explanation above.

As usual, thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Are you using iOS8 preview SDK ? I cannot build your project

Comment: Oh man....shame on me.  Yes, actually I was.  Sorry - I should have mentioned that.  Strangely, this example works perfectly fine with the official XCode and iOS7.  Will have to log this with them.  Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this issue is specifically related to the iOS8 preview.  Compiling with the official XCode and iOS7 runs the example just fine.

Thanks to Antzi